# Formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments

Tags: r, plot

I have translated a program from R to C++. The program in question runs multiple iterations of  itself with different values then produces a histogram and plot. C++ graphs are finicky so I decided to save the values in csv format and graph them in R. The files are fairly large, for smaller size files, 10 iterations produces 23000 rows and 3 columns. Of course this increase drastically for 100 or 1000 iterations. The format of the csv files is 
1,3,0.0107171
which corresponds to col num, row num and data. Then I run this into R:

```
>data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
>plot(data,type="b", pch=19, xlab="X", ylab="Y")
Error in plot.default(...) : 
  formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

As a side note:

```
> hist(data[,3], xlab="Step length (m)", main="")
```

the histogram works without any problems. Please tell me if i can provide any more details, I am not so good when it comes to R so I might be missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are passing a three column data.frame to `plot.default`. What exactly were you expecting it to produce?

Comment: Did you want a pseudo-3d plot. Then `persp` might be more interesting.

Answer (score 8):

You are passing a data.frame to `plot`, which dispatches `plot.data.frame`, which will, for a data.frame with more than 2 columns, call

```
pairs(data.matrix(data))
```

So you could pass arguments in `...` that are valid for `pairs` (`type` is  not)

However I think you probably want to think about what you want to plot from your data

- What should be on the x axis
- What should be on the y axis

And then create your call to `plot` (or perhaps `matplot`) as required.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this indicated that my input data structure was not numeric.
I solved it using `as.numeric`, as follows:

```
plot(as.numeric(df[1, 1:9]), as.numeric(df[2, 1:9]),   
    las = 2, type = "l", 
    col = colrs[3],lwd = lwds[1], ylim = c(0, 1.05*maxnumb), xlim = c(-0.6, yAx), main = weDraw, ylab = "OD 600", xlab = "hours", xaxt = "n")
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for late reply. I encountered this and it was due to passing the plot function a data.frame from inside another function. The work around was to simply do this:

`do.plot <- function(df = plot.df[c(1, 2), ])
{`
**as.matrix(df)**
`plot(.....)}`